# Static folder in the wrong subdirectory

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I am trying to setup a static folder for my project.

I am trying to place the static files in the following folder: 
`/portfolio-project/portfolio/static`

I have made the following additions to `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'portfolio/static/'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

However, after running `collectstatic` the static folder is created in: `/portfolio-project/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize STATIC_ROOT if you want to.

in your case

```
STATIC_URL = '/portfolio/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'portfolio/static/')
```

Comment: Hi Athul, Thank you for your suggestion. When  I run runserver with you solution I get the following error; django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.
System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced). Although with your solution the static files are in the correct subdirectory.

Comment: If the static root is the same with static_dirs, no need to set it in your settings. STATICFILES_DIRS is the list of folders where Django will search for additional static files, in addition to each static folder of each app installed. STATIC_ROOT is the folder where every static files will be stored after a manage.py collectstatic